# Problems with Kohana Logs

Tags: kohana-3, logging

For some reason I cannot get kohana to log my custom errors. Here is the code:

```
$log = new Log;
$log->add(Log::ERROR, 'There was a conflic with the username and/or email. UUID: '.$user['uuid'].' username: '.$user['username'].' email: '.$user['email']);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Check to make sure apache can write to your log dir.

Comment: @tylerl, if I'm not mistaken, Kohana won't even start if the log folders are not writable.

Comment: Laurent is right. The Kohana errors do show up in the logs folder. It's the custom one that does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use Kohana's built-in logger since it's already setup:

```
Kohana::$log->add(Log::ERROR, "your debug info")->write();
```

Otherwise, if you want to use a custom one, make sure you assign a writer to it - it can be file, database, etc.

Comment: There is no need for adding `->write()` to that line. This is done automatically.